# Boost Gil is able to rasterize a font?

Tags: c++, boost, fonts, boost-gil

I would like to ask if with Boost Gil alone I can render text into an image using a custom ttf/otf font, my impression is that there is no such thing in Boost Gil, and so I should adopt something like [freetype](http://freetype.org/), but since I don't like to add yet another dependency if I can possibly avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a Freetype GIL extension by Tom Brinkman here:

- [boost/gil/extension/toolbox/](https://github.com/boost-gil/gil-contributions-archive/tree/sandbox/boost/gil/extension/toolbox) (imported from code.google.com archive)

(I think it's probably in `toolbox/freegil.h`). I found anouncements on the boost mailing list around [here](https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2007/04/119826.php).

Comment: I'm not familiar with `svn` but if I checkout this I can't see the same file that I can see through the web interface, I need to checkout some sub-module or sub-project like with `git` ? I see `freegil.hpp` online but I can't locate it inside my copy of the repository .

Comment: @user2485710 I have just updated the broken links in the the answer.